# does resbmit paper go to the same reviewer?

Tags: elsevier

We sent paper to a reputed journal. After 4 months we get:
Reviewers have now commented on your paper. You will see that they are advising that you revise your manuscript. If you are prepared to undertake the work required, I would be pleased to reconsider my decision.

Im confusing about revise? what it does means? The reviews was easy and we already resbmit them. Does the paper will be reviewed by the same reviewers? What is our change for our paper to be accepted? how long in average will take to get the decision?

Comment: The editor and the reviewers decide.

Comment: You've got several questions bundled together here, which makes this difficult to answer directly. Some will be answered by the "typical workflow" question. After you read that, I would suggest trying to ask each individual left-over question directly.

Answer (score 4):

> Does the paper will be reviewed by the same reviewers?

Authors, editors, and reviewers, would all surely prefer resubmissions to be reviewed by the same reviewers. (Authors want their changes evaluated, editors want their selected reviewers to see the process through, and reviewers want to ensure their concerns have been addressed.) However, reviewers may be unavailable or may decide to no longer participate (perhaps they've seen enough of the paper already), or editors may include a new reviewer to get a better perspective. So, **resubmissions may be reviewed by different reviewers**.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the journal in question -- many have very clunky interfaces on their manuscript management systems. From what you say, it looks like the paper has been reviewed and somewhere in the system, there should be reviewers' comments. Most journals will send revisions to the same reviewers. Depending on the journal, the journal editor and other factors, reviews can take a long time. If in doubt, you should contact the journal's editor.